# Why Images are not appended to the div

Tags: jquery, jsp

Why are the images in the array are not shown in div

I am trying to append the images to the div defined below , but they are not being shown in div .

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Hello World Alert box</title>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">  
</script>
<script>
var content = "";
var myArray = ['D:/1146Wj.jpg', 'D:/1146Wj.jpg','D:/1146Wj.jpg'];
myArray.forEach(function (element) {
alert(element);
  content += "<div><a href='#'><img src=" + element + "   /></a></div>";
 $("#container").html(content);
});

</script>
</head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#cl").click(function(){
alert("HELLO WORLD!");
});
});
</script>
<body>
<font color="red">CLICK BELOW BUTTON TO SEE ALERT BOX</font>
<br>
<br>
<button id="cl">Click Me</button>
<div id="container">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do the alerts work as expected? Otherwise, check in the console (Ctrl+Shift+J in FF, F12 in IE afaik). You could try adding `file:///D:/` to the src path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your for loop is wrong

```
myArray.forEach(function (element) {
alert(element);
  content = "<div><a href='#'><img src=" + element + "   /></a></div>";
 $("#container").append(content);
});
```

Check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/J3JJD/3/)

Make sure you have this for loop inside your $(document).ready

Comment: Putting inside document.ready was working , Thank you very much , one more question how can i add class to that div ??

Comment: content = $('<div></div>');
content.addClass('your-classname');

Comment: you mean it should be $("#container").addClass('myclass'); $("#container").append(content);

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you append your images to the DOM after the document has loaded (put your code inside $(document).ready())

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons.

First because at the time the script is evaluated, the HTML page has not been loaded yet and the dom is not ready. So the div can't be found and modified by jQuery. You need to enclose the script into a callback function and register this callback function with `$(document).ready()`.

Second because HTML pages are not supposed to access the local drive of the end user to load images. And even if they did, it would need to use the file:// protocol. The images should be served over HTTP, as your page is.

Comment: Judging by the <title> tag (jQuery Hello World Alert box>), he is trying to learn some jQuery. Loading images from the local drive is ok for that.

Comment: i am basically into back end now as part of my work i need to add images from a folder to the jsp page on Ajax call

Comment: The folder must be accessible through HTTP, and the path of the image must be the path over HTTP, not the path on the local drive. End users don't have access to the local drive of your server.